# VS2010 C++ debug how the application handles an exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception

And first of all thanks for reading this and any advise.

How can one debug how an exception is handled by an application. This is a legacy code base with built-in exception handling that has recently been converted to 64bit. Upon encountering an error / exception the whole system hangs.

During regular application use these freezes can not be reliably reproduced. There is however test code in the application to throw unhandled exceptions that reproduced the freeze.

When running under the debugger it obviously breaks on the exception - an access violation for example - but so far I could not figure out a way to basically tell the debugger to just pass it on to the application. Using "Continue" or stepping appears to just repeatedly tell me there is an access violation. Using WinDbg instead of VS 2010 did not help the situation either.

Q: Are there some low level tricks in VS2010 or WinDbg available that would allow me to break on an exception but then really pass it down to the application for handling to debug how the application deals with it?

Or to say it in another way: I want VS2010 / WinDbg to show me the application code that is executed after / in response to an exception and not the exception itself.

Side note: The goal right now is to prevent the system hang requiring a hard reset of the computer. An application only crash is 'should' be avoided and a deterministic application shutdown would be acceptable.

Thanks again,
T

Edit: After considering WhozCraig's comment changed "freeze" to "hang" which might be a slightly better term. Either way the system does not respond to any user interactions - with the only relief being a hard reset.

Comment: OT: Ok I have to ask just for the inquisition in everyone else thinking it right now.. What in the *hell* are you doing in that code that wedges the *kernel* on that box? An unhandled exception should eventually reach the default handler which just terminates the process. What have you done to cause *that* to also hang the machine?

Comment: Good question. The application communicates with external components via a PCIe interface. With the current assumption being that this communication path is not shutdown correctly when we encounter an exception.

We can reproduce the issue with a C# app where we can also 'fix' it - meaning deterministic shutdown of that C# app instead of system freeze - by handling the AppDomain.UnhandledException and taking appropriate steps to shutdown the hardware link correctly.

Comment: Oh Lord, you didn't think that mentioning PCIe in your question was important?  Run man, run.  http://careers.stackoverflow.com/